# Second onClick listener in a new activity

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick, onclicklistener

I just started to learn Java. I know some C++, but you know, I am just a novice. I have a problem with a button. I a main activity there are 3 buttons with onClick discovered by switch. By clicking on one of the buttons you're redirected to another activity where I need to create a new button.

The code responsible for MainScreen buttons looks like this (and it works):

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button act_2x2, act_3x3, act_4x4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    act_2x2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Activity_2x2);
    act_3x3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Activity_3x3);
    act_4x4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Activity_4x4);

    act_2x2.setOnClickListener(this);
    act_3x3.setOnClickListener(this);
    act_4x4.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.Activity_2x2:
            Intent inent1 = new Intent(this, macierz_2x2.class);
            startActivity(inent1);
            break;

        case R.id.Activity_3x3:
            Intent inent2 = new Intent(this, macierz_3x3.class);
            startActivity(inent2);
            break;

        case R.id.Activity_4x4:
            Intent inent3 = new Intent(this, macierz_4x4.class);
            startActivity(inent3);
            break;
    }
```

And it is okay, I can normally enter the new activity, for example Activity_2x2.
Here, in 2x2 class I've created a new OnClickListener and when I click on it, nothing happens. I am sitting here for two hours with debugger, it is saying that I don't have permissions, but It is impossible, because it is just a simple button. I am using Android Studio and just don't know how to debug correctly.

Here is the definition:

```
public class macierz_2x2 extends MainScreen implements View.OnClickListener{

Button b_2x2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2x2);
    b_2x2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2x2);
    b_2x2.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

public void OnClick(View view) {
    what happens after clicking
    }

I know, that this problem is somewhere in overriding and extending, but no idea, why the compiller is letting this being compiled.

If someone have any idea, I will be grateful.

ps. I don't need an answer, just a point, what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class macierz_2x2 extends MainScreen implements View.OnClickListener{
```

MainScreen already implements `View.OnClickListener`. Remove it from the definition of your class.

```
public class macierz_2x2 extends MainScreen {
```

is enough. You can override onClick on your macierz_2x2 activity

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
      R.id.button_2x2:
        // do something
        break;
      default:
        super.onClick(view);
        break;
     }
}
```